# How do I identify which plugin an Eclipse editor comes from?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Two cases I run into a lot:

1. This editor is great, I should add this plugin to my other Eclipse environments
2. This looks like a bug, where do I go for more information?

I don't even need the plugin explicitly identified -- just the full classname of the editor would generally be enough.  It sounds like I could do this with [PDE](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/), but I feel like there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDE's Plug-in Spy (Alt+Shift+F1) **is** how you do it.  If you think that's too hard, I'm not sure what to tell you.

Comment: Thanks for the condescension. And yes, that amount of work for such a simple bit of information is ridiculous.  That said, it did get me a raw classname, from which I could divine the responsible plugin, so it does meet the bare minimum of what I need.

Comment: Then you probably did something wrong. The plugin-spy lists the contributing plugin directly in its output.